# SQLAlchemy insert data dumped on the database A into the database B

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

What is the most effective way to insert data dumped on the database A into the database B? Normally I would use `mysqldump` for the task like this, but because of the *complex query* I had to take a different approach. At present I have the following inefficient solution:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, INTEGER, CHAR, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()
SessFactory = sessionmaker()


print('## Configure database connections')
db_one = create_engine('mysql://root:pwd1@127.0.0.1/db_one', echo=True).connect()
sess_one = SessFactory(bind=db_one)
db_two = create_engine('mysql://root:pwd2@127.0.0.2/db_two', echo=True).connect()
sess_two = SessFactory(bind=db_two)


## Declare query to dump data
dump_query = (
    'SELECT A.id, A.name, B.address '
    'FROM table_a A JOIN table_b B '
    'ON A.id = B.id_c WHERE '
    'A.deleted = 0'
)


print('## Fetch data on db_one')
data = db_one.execute(dump_query).fetchall()


## Declare table on db_two
class cstm_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cstm_table'
    pk = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(CHAR(36), nullable=False)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(150), default=None)
    address = Column(VARCHAR(150), default=None)


print('## Recreate "cstm_table" on db_two')
cstm_table.__table__.drop(bind=db_two, checkfirst=True)
cstm_table.__table__.create(bind=db_two)


print('## Insert dumped data into the "cstm_table" on db_two')
for row in data:
    insert = cstm_table.__table__.insert().values(row)
    db_two.execute(insert)
```

This execute sequentially over a 100K inserts (horrible).

I also tried:

```
with db_two.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin() as trans:
        row_as_dict = [dict(row.items()) for row in data]
        try:
            conn.execute(cstm_table.__table__.insert(), row_as_dict)
        except:
            trans.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            trans.commit()
```

But then after inserting ~20 rows I get error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

The following also does the job, but I'm not so sure it's the most efficient:

```
sess_two.add_all([cstm_table(**dict(row.items())) for row in data])
sess_two.flush()
sess_two.commit()
```

Comment: Not sure if MySQL's FEDERATED tables could be used to dump data between 2 server instances in this case, but might be worth a look.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately one of my DBs live in the AWS RDS, where to my best knowledge FEDERATED tables are not supported.